# Python Multiprocessing Pool get stuck when reading files

Tags: python, multiprocessing

In my main script I am first executing a function get_files() which produces and saves the following outputs:
file1.pkl
file2.pkl
file3.pkl
file4.pkl

I then want to process the files using pythons multiprocessing module. Here are the contents of my main.py

```
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing

def get_files(filename):
    # get some data
    for i in range(4):
        data.to_pickle(filename + str(i+1))

def process(file):
    object = pd.read_pickle(file)
    # do some processing
    return object

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
pool.map(process, [file1, file2, file3, file4])
```

For some reason my pool gets stuck when reading the files. However when I execute the main script again without first executing get_files() files have already been save, I have no issues. Does anybody know the reason why this might be?

Comment: what do you mean "gets stuck"? Where?

Comment: The pool gets stuck when importing the pickled files

Comment: This is very hard to reason about without an MCVE. What if you just run `process(somefile)` without  multiprocessing?

Comment: Can we see your actual code?